# Soundpool Handler Issues (Cannot maintain tempo)

Tags: android, performance, handler, soundpool

I have been trying to create a simple metronome app in android using soundpool, however, I have noticed that at higher BPM values the sound delays are not consistent. Sometimes the lag between two beats are higher than expected and sometimes there is no lag at all (double beats).

```
player = new SoundPool.Builder()
            .setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                    .build())
            .setMaxStreams(1)
            .build();
    tick = player.load(this, R.raw.tick_6mil, 1);
    player.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int i, int i1) {
            setupHandler();
        }
    });


//Running at 360BPM (~166.67ms per beat)
public void setupHandler(){
    r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 167);
            player.play(tick, 1, 1, 10, 0, 1);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, 167);
}
```

I am not sure what the issue is here other than soundpool play call having inconsistent overheads, and that is an issue that I cannot fix. Any help/insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Android has never been great at handling sounds, due to horrible lags. Unfortunately, iOS seems to be much better at it.